# What is wrong with this algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm

I was trying to solve **Project Euler Problem #2** : *Find the sum of the even terms of the fibonaci series upto 4,000,000.* Ex : Upto 1000, the sum is 2+8+34+144+610 = 798.

Now, my algo was to add every third fibonaci number from 2 onwards - as every third fibonaci number is bound to be even following the logic:

Even : E, Odd : O,

```
O+E=O    E+O=O    O+O=E
1+2=3    2+3=5    5+3=8    (example)
```

So, I wrote the following code to figure out the answer..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define LT 4000000
int main()
{
    double i0,i1,sum=0,cycle,eSum=2,status=1;
    i0 = 1;
    i1 = 2;

    while(i1<LT && status == 1)
    {
        for(cycle=3;cycle>0;cycle--)
        {
            sum=i0+i1;
            i0=i1;
            i1=sum;

            if((i1+i0)>LT)
            {
                status = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        eSum+=(status == 1)?sum:0;
    }
    printf("\nThe required Answer: %8.0f\n",eSum);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it *works correctly for **LT = 1000***, but for the problem, which requires LT=4,000,000, the program shows a wrong value of **1089154**, instead of the correct value of **4613732**.

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. Also, I don't understand how it can work correctly for LT=1000, but not for a greater number.. Am I missing something embarrassingly obvious? Please Help..

Comment: For starters, recode everything using long not double.

Comment: Hint: when your numeric algorithm works for small numbers, but fails for large numbers, look for overflows. I think the point of PE#2 was teaching you precisely this.

Comment: If you need 64 bit integeres, big hint here: on posix, use `#include <inttypes.h>` and uint64_t or int64_t. For Windows, use __int64.

Comment: I really don't think that the reason is overflow, because the program has no problem with printing double values greater than 4,000,000 - or even double that.. Plus, i tried to change the double to long, as per dasblinkenlight's suggestion.. Still got the wrong answer.. This seems really odd..

Comment: @Somu `long` may be as short as 32 bits whereas `double` can almost always represent integers up to 2 to the 51th power.

Comment: Also, if I were to use modulus, the correct answer is obtained using double variable.. But I want to avoid divisions, and want to know what is wrong with this particular code, so that i never make the same mistake again..

Comment: @Somu huh? why would a `double` be necessary for performing modulo arithmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is exiting loop too soon.  Change test to `sum` rather than `i1+i0` which is the *next* `sum`.

```
    for(cycle=3;cycle>0;cycle--) {
        sum=i0+i1;
        i0=i1;
        i1=sum;
        // if((i1+i0)>LT)
        if(sum>LT)
        {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

As your numbers are in the range [1 ... 2*4,000,000], you will get acceptable results using `long`, `unsigned long`, `float`, `double`.   As this is an integer problem, recommend using integers.

Answer (score 0):

The inner for looks kind of strnage, and you shouldn't use double for natural numbers.
Try solething like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define LT 4000000
int main()
{
  long i0,i1,sum=0,eSum=2;
  int counter = 0;
  i0 = 1;
  i1 = 1;

  while(sum<LT)
  {
    sum=i0+i1;
    i0=i1;
    i1=sum;

    eSum+=((counter++ % 3 == 0) && ( sum <= LT))?sum:0;
  }
  printf("\nThe required Answer: %8.0f\n",eSum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid divisions and/or modulus operations to keep the processor expenditure to a minimum..

Comment: @Somu operating on 4 million numbers ain't no real CPU usage. Just **don't worry about efficiency.**

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, I just wanted to do it without divisions as an extra challenge.. I already did it that way(which is how I got to know the answer), and this is just an exercise for me..

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#define LT 4000000
typedef uint64_t Numtype;
int main( void )
{
    Numtype n0 = 1;
    Numtype n1 = 1;
    Numtype n2 = 0;
    Numtype sum = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        n2 = n0 + n1;
        if ( n2 > LT ) break;
        if ( n2 % 2 == 0 ) sum += n2;
        n0 = n1;
        n1 = n2;
    }

    printf("\nThe required Answer: %ld\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```